# Access DataGrid Cell value

Tags: wpf, vb.net, datagrid

I Have a Column A,B,C (Simplified) in DataGrid. This DataGrid is bind to a DataTable and Column C value is the difference of A and B i.e ( A - B ). Column A and B are editable. Now My requirement is that when the user change the value of A Or B the value of column C should be updated accordingly. To do so I have wrote **CellEditEnding** Event. In this event I am able to get the row but not the value that user just have modified. If I get the corrorponding value from the DataTable I got the Old value i.e the value before modification by the user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using below code in your CellEndEditing event

```
((TextBox)e.EditingElement).Text
```

Or

```
ContentPresenter contentPresenter = e.EditingElement as ContentPresenter;
        DataTemplate editingTemplate = contentPresenter.ContentTemplate;
        TextBox txtMyTextBox = editingTemplate.FindName("textbox1", contentPresenter) as TextBox;
        string newValue = txtMyTextBox.Text;
```

Comment: It Didn't Work, e.EditingElement is of type ContentPresenter not TextBox so I am not able to extract the text